# Cannot change default value of number input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, input, default-value

I am using Javascript (not familiar with frameworks like Angular just yet), and trying to get and display the value of a number input from my HTML, but when I run the function that does this, the default value of "1" from the HTML seems to be the only one used, even if I change the input on the website itself to, say, 10 by clicking the arrows.

I think I've written the code correctly as far as syntax goes, so my only thought is that perhaps the input has to be wrapped in a form of some kind, and the "roll" button changed to type="submit"?

Here is a link to a [codepen](https://codepen.io/lumberjon1/pen/oNeRzmW) with the broken code, and some snippets of the involved pieces below.

```js
var displayScreen = document.getElementById("display-message");
var rollButton = document.getElementById("roll-button");

//Variable to tell the rollDice() function how many times to roll dice.
var numDice = document.getElementById("num-dice").value;

//Dice Array to hold the results of the rollDice() function, gets cleared after each use.
var diceTotal = [];

//Event listener for the "roll" button
rollButton.addEventListener("click", rollDice);

//Make this function display a roll result
function displayMessage() {

  displayScreen.innerText = diceTotal[0];
}

//Generate a random number between 1 and diceType, and set the rolledNumber variable to its result
function rollDice() {

  //Nothing currently changes numDice, so it keeps default value="1".

  result = 0;
  var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * diceType) + 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < numDice; i++) {
    result += roll;
  }

  diceTotal[0] = result;

  displayMessage();
}
```

```html
<div id="dice-display-div">

  <!--
                We want to display the dice roll total, any applied bonuses, and then the final total
                together in this div, possibly as separate <h2> elements.
            -->

  <h2 id="display-message">Click "Roll" to Begin</h2>

</div>

<div id="roll-button-div">

  <label class="roll-button-label" for="num-dice" id="num-dice-label">Number of Dice: </label>
  <input class="roll-button-item" type="number" id="num-dice" name="num-dice" value="1" min="1" max="10">

  <label class="roll-button-label" for="bonus" id="bonus-label">Bonus (or Negative): </label>
  <input class="roll-button-item" type="number" id="bonus" name="bonus" value="0" min="-10" max="10">

  <button class="roll-button-item" id="roll-button">Roll</button>

</div>
```

Comment: You need to get the value of the input in the `rollDice()` function. You're just setting `numDice` once when the page is loaded.

Comment: Why is `diceTotal` an array>?

Comment: @Barmar thanks, this makes a lot of sense when I think about it in terms of a page loading these items.  That's still taking some getting used to.  The variable is an array because I had originally outlined this thinking of adding array indexes together, then scrapped that but kept it as an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should call your Math.random() inside the for loop, otherwise you will only randomly generate one number, and all your dice will have that same number. Second, you should assign `numDice` inside your function so it rechecks and assigns the current value instead of at the start of page render:

```
var displayScreen = document.getElementById("display-message");
var rollButton = document.getElementById("roll-button");



//Dice Array to hold the results of the rollDice() function, gets cleared after each use.
var diceTotal = [];

//Event listener for the "roll" button
rollButton.addEventListener("click", rollDice);

//Make this function display a roll result
function displayMessage() {

    displayScreen.innerText = diceTotal[0];
}

//Generate a random number between 1 and diceType, and set the rolledNumber variable to its result
function rollDice() {
   //Variable to tell the rollDice() function how many times to roll dice.
   var numDice = document.getElementById("num-dice").value; //assign this upon function call so it checks it each time the button is clicked to get the latest value
   //Nothing currently changes numDice, so it keeps default value="1".

   result = 0;
   var roll = 0

   for (var i = 0; i < numDice; i++) {
       roll =  Math.floor(Math.random() * diceType) + 1; //call random on each dice roll
       result += roll;
   }

   diceTotal[0] = result;

  displayMessage();
}
```